# ssrs leading zeroes and only show decimals when necessary

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a SSRS report which needs to show leading zeroes if the item has decimals and is less than one, but only show decimals if needed. I'll try to break this down via examples.

35.00 should be displayed as 35

35.5 should be displayed as 35.50

.01 should be displayed as 0.01

01 should be displayed as 1

I have the decimal portion of this working by using Format(value, "##.##") but I am struggling a bit with the leading zeroes portion of things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not something that can be achieved by using format strings on there own. However... If you convert your value to double using the `CDbl` function and output that, then set your format string on the text-box to custom, and use

```
=iif(CDbl(Fields!val.Value)=Floor(CDbl(Fields!val.Value)),"0","0.00")
```

[image: Format Number Example]

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. I would have never thought of that.